# Pointers Linked Lists C Programming

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I don't get why this isn't working... For example I have this.

```
struct node {
    int data;
    struct node* next;
};

static int length(struct node* head) {
   Does Stuff

};

void main() (  
   int i; 
   struct node* head;
   i = length(head);
);
```

but the code doesn't want to work... I get the wrong output. I'm trying to send the pointer to my functions so that they can have access to the data that I malloc. I will post the full code bellow:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node* next;
};

static int length(struct node* head);
static void push(struct node* head, int data);
static int pop(struct node* head);
static void appendNode(struct node* head, int data);
static struct node *copyList(struct node* head);
static void printList(struct node* head);



/************************************************************
 length - return length of a list
 ************************************************************/
int length(struct node* head) {
    int count = 0;
    struct node* current = NULL;

    current = head;
    while (current != NULL) {
        current = current->next;
        ++count;
    }

    return count;
}


/************************************************************
 push - add new node at beginning of list
 ************************************************************/
void push(struct node* head, int data) {
    struct node* new_ptr = NULL;

    new_ptr = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new_ptr->data = data;
    new_ptr->next = head;

    head = new_ptr;
}

/************************************************************
 pop - delete node at beginning of non-empty list and return its data
 ************************************************************/
int pop(struct node* head) {
    int val = 0;
    struct node* temp = NULL;

    if (head != NULL) {
        val = head->data;
        temp = head->next;
        free(head);
        head = temp;
    }

    return(val);
}

/************************************************************
 appendNode - add new node at end of list
 ************************************************************/
void appendNode(struct node* head, int data) {
    struct node* current = NULL;
    struct node* previous = NULL;
    struct node* new_ptr = NULL;

    current = head;
    previous = current;
    while (current != NULL) {
        previous = current;
        current = current->next;
    }

    new_ptr = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new_ptr->data = data;
    new_ptr->next = NULL;

    previous = new_ptr;

}

/************************************************************
 copyList - return new copy of list
 ************************************************************/
struct node* copyList(struct node* head) {
    struct node* copy = NULL;
    struct node* current = NULL;
    struct node* new_ptr = NULL;

    /* Copy current head to copy */
    current = head;
    while (current != NULL) {
        appendNode(copy, current->data);
        current = current->next;
    }

    return copy;
}


/************************************************************
 printList - print linked list as "List: < 2, 5, 6 >" (example)
 ************************************************************/
void printList(struct node* head) {
    struct node* current = NULL;

    printf("List: < ");

    current = head;
    if (current == NULL)
        printf("none ");

    while (current != NULL) {
        printf("%d", current->data);
        current = current->next;
        if (current != NULL)
            printf(", ");
    }

    printf(" >\n");
}

void main() {
    int i;                      // index used for loops
    struct node *list_a;        // a new list
    struct node *list_a_copy;   // copy of list
    list_a = NULL;                // initialize empty list
    list_a_copy = NULL;           // initialize empy list


    // test push
    for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        push(list_a, i);

    // test length
    printf("Length of list = %d\n", length(list_a));

    // test print head list
    printf("head:\n");
    printList(list_a);

    // test append node
    for (i = 4; i < 8; ++i)
        appendNode(list_a, i);

    // test print head list
    printf("head(append):\n");
    printList(list_a);

    // make a copy of list
    list_a_copy = copyList(list_a);

    // test pop head list
    for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        printf("%d popped\n", pop(list_a));

    // test print copy list
    printf("head copy:\n");
    printList(list_a_copy);

    // test pop copy list
    for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        printf("%d popped\n", pop(list_a_copy));

}
```

Thank you for you help. I'm still learning these C pointers, and I know I'm close.

Cheers

Comment: You asking about hte long code, or the short code?
The short code pass an uninitialized pointer to the length function. That's bad.

Comment: The first code was an example, obviously is was not "complete." I guess it was confusing, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked into function push():

```
void push(struct node* head, int data) {
    struct node* new_ptr = NULL;

    new_ptr = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new_ptr->data = data;
    new_ptr->next = head;

    head = new_ptr;
}
```

The way you assign `head = new_ptr;` is wrong. Doing so only, `head` has effect within in the function, `head` won't be pointed to the memory you allocated after push() is called. So you need to fix your push() function:

```
void push(struct node **head, int data) {
    if ((*head) == null)
        (*head) = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    (*head)->data = data;
    (*head)->next = head;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are passing a pointer to a node in your methods. This means that what you are modifying is a local parameter and not what you are passing to the method. Why is this? Because passing by value copies the parameter, to the address is directly copied.

```
struct Node *list_a = NULL;
push(list_a, 5);
```

When you call `push`, what happens is that a copy of the variable `list_a` is pushed onto the stack and then the function is called. The same thing, if you think about it, happens with simple cases:

```
int x = 5;
add(x, 5);

void add(int a, int b) { a += b; } // <-- this won't modify the x passed
```

So here

```
void push(struct Node *head, int value) {
  head = something;
}
```

you are not modifying the original `list_a` but rather a copy of it which has been passed to the function.

To be able to modify the original pointer you need to pass the address to it, so a pointer to the pointer of the head of the list. This can be done easily:

```
struct Node *list_a = NULL;
push(&node, 5);

void push (struct Node **node, int value) {
  ...
  *node = malloc(..);
}
```

So here the address of the variable `list_a` is passed to the function, dereferencing it allows you to modify the real value instead that just a copy.